# how to wrap App component while using sentry with codepush react native

Tags: react-native, sentry, code-push, react-native-code-push, react-native-sentry

while using sentry with appcenter's codepush how to wrap the main App component
like this:

```
export default Sentry.wrap(codePush(App));
```

or like this:

```
export default codePush(Sentry.wrap(App));
```

or is there any other method to execute the above task
I refereed to the sentry docs but was unclear about this part
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/manual-setup/codepush/

please can someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED

Sentry recommends having CodePush as the outermost layer. An edit to their docs reads:

> In case you are wrapping your Root Component with `Sentry.wrap` to gain Performance features, `codePush` should be the outer most function because it needs access to the very root component in order to swap out the bundle.

```js
export default codePush(Sentry.wrap(App));
```

Thanks to @manoelneto for correcting my assumption there.

OLD ANSWER (INCORRECT)

I would recommend having Sentry as the outermost layer. That way, if CodePush causes a crash, Sentry will know about it.

Comment: I've improved the docs about that https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-docs/pull/5483